# Group Theory: Dummit and Foote Exercise 3.2.6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm currently self studying Dummit and Foote and I'm stuck on exercise 3.2.6

Exercise 3.2.6: Let $H \le G$ and let $g \in G$. Prove that if the right coset $Hg$ equals some left coset of $H$ in $G$ then it equals the left coset $gH$ and $g$ must be in $N_{G}(H)$

My Attempt: We need show that if $g_{1}H = Hg_{2}$ then $g_{1} = g_{2}$. By assumption $g_{1}H = Hg_{2}$ so we may write $g_{1}h_{1} = h_{2}g_{2}$ for some $h_{1},h_{2} \in H$. Thus, $g_{1}h_{1}g_{2}^{-1} = h_{2} \ldots$

I realize at this point that I'm close to concluding that $g_{1}$ (equivalently $g_{2}$) is in $N_{G}(H)$ if $g_{1} = g_{2}$ but I'm having trouble proving that $g_{1} = g_{2}$. In any attempt at manipulating the elements I never seem to arrive at a point where I can conclude that $g_{1} = g_{2}$. I would prefer a hint rather than a solution if possible.

Comment: It's not the case that if $g_1H=Hg_2$ then $g_1=g_2$.

Comment: Actually, you should show that $g_1 H = H g_1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $g_{1}H = Hg_{2}$, we get $g_2=e g_2=g_1 h$, for some $h \in H$.

Then $g_{1}H = Hg_{2} = H g_1 h$.

I'll let you finish.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your argument. Continuing from where you left off, we know that $g_{1}H = Hg_{1}h$. It follows that $g_{1}Hh^{-1} = Hg_{1}$, but $H \le G$ so $g_{1}Hh^{-1} = g_{1}H = Hg_{1}$.

Comment: @Twiss013, exactly!